# C# - PDF AxAcroPDFLib and AcroPDFLib, missing functions?

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I was trying to display a PDF file. After long research in google, stack, and msdn, I found few options. Libs from Adobe was first hit, but unsuccessful.

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fJFR.png) to album with properties, events and code.

None of the functions and properties from answers were found here. I added .COM control to toolbox, put in Form, and added "usings". As in pictures.

And here I have few questions to this topic:
1. What did I wrong, that this hasn't got their functions? 
2. Can I use this libs in commercial program? 
3. Does user must have install Adobe Reader to run my program?

Later on I found another clearly commercial libs, but I can't afford their license.

Last one was "PDFSharp", but I can't understand where to put code from this [sample](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/documentviewer-sample.ashx).

If someone could recommend a lib, or program which is:
Independent (I would like not force to instal Adobe Reader, for example).
Display PDF. 
Move through PDF pages (scroll bars, and change index of actual page).
And actually that's all. Even simple conversion from PDF to ImageBox would be enough.

Thank You all in advance for all help.

Comment: You may also use the WebBrowser Control. myWebBrowser.Navigate("C:\\myDir\\myFile.pdf") ;

Comment: @Graffito Thank You. Actually You used full path to file, and it is working.  I was trying to do by myself earlier  but passing only "myFile.pdf", even if that PDF is in the same directory as *exe won't work. 

Does user have to install Adobe Reader previously to view PDF this way?

Comment: I've just checked. Adobe is a must in this case.

Comment: Try [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com). It's a class library based on the Google PDFium project for viewing, navigating, editing and extracting texts from PDF files in .NET projects and do not require Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: I'd recommend iTextSharp: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (and 2) It can be related to [the latest changes](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1842456?start=0&tstart=0) in Adobe Reader COM objects that broke Adobe Reader controls on Windows x64. The solution is to use WebBrowser control instead (and expect that it will call PDF plugin) OR to compile your application targeted x86 instead of AnyCPU.
2. If you rely on Adobe PDF pluggin then yes, user should have Adobe Reader installed and must explicitly [permit PDF plugin in Internet Explorer](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html).